# Changing the Database Schema on a linking table (many-to-many) in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am creating a many to many relationships with my EF Models.  The linking table is being created which is fine, but it keeps putting it on the DBO Schema which I do not want.  Yes, I could just modify the migration script after its generated but that should be (hoping there is) a way to do this so the schema just works.

From my OnModelCreating Method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
            .WithMany(x => x.Users)
            .Map(x => {
                x.ToTable("Users.UsersAddresses");
                x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                x.MapRightKey("AddressId");
            });
```

From the Generated Script:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.[Users.UsersAddresses]",
    c => new
        {
            UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            AddressId = c.Long(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.AddressId })
    .ForeignKey("Users.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .ForeignKey("Users.Addresses", t => t.AddressId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.UserId)
    .Index(t => t.AddressId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToTable` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696559%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) in which you can specify the schema name:

```
x.ToTable("UsersAddresses", "Users");
```

Comment: PERFECT!  I should have paid attention to the overloads more.

Answer (score 1):

From EF6 onwards you can use:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(“nameOfDefaultSchema”);
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not solve my problem as I am using schemas to group tables by categories.  BUT this is good knowledge to have.